# Grub doesn't recognize Windows after Ubuntu 12.10 installation

Tags: installation, 12.10, boot, grub2, dual-boot

I've got a problem: After installing Ubuntu 12.10 grub doesn't recognize Windows 7 and I only can boot Ubuntu. I wrote the windows entry into the grub config, but it didn't start also.

I don't know if it is a problem by the partitions or by grub itself.

Does anyone have had the same issue or has heard about it?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: are you sure you havn't overwrite the windows partition with ubuntu? which option did you selected in installer? `install alongside windows`? give a try to [`boot-repair`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry you have the issue, this can be frustrating, try the following utility and let me know if it helps you.

Boot-Repair is a simple tool to repair frequent boot issues you may encounter in Ubuntu like when you can't boot Ubuntu after installing Windows or another Linux distribution, or when you can't boot Windows after installing Ubuntu, or when GRUB is not displayed anymore, some upgrade breaks GRUB, etc.

This can also be performed from a live-CD or live-USB.

Either add ‘ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair’ to your Software Sources via the Software Centre or, for speeds-sake, add it using a new Terminal session:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

Boot-Repair can be installed & used from any Ubuntu session (normal session, or live-CD, or live-USB). PPA packages are available for Ubuntu 10.04, 10.10, 11.04, 11.10, 12.04 and 12.10.

Answer (score -1):

yes your quary is right..
this problem is coming due to installation of windows after ubuntu.because the boot loader of windows NTLDR is not the chain loader.so it can't boot ubuntu only can windows..
the solution of this problem is that you should take windows before ubuntu.